# ggplot not showing data

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, dataframe

I am trying to make a nice plot with ggplot. However, I do not know why it is not showing data.

Here is some minimum code

```
dummylabels <- c("A","B","C")
dummynumbers <- c(1,2,3)
dummy_frame <- data.frame(dummylabels,dummynumbers)
p= ggplot(data=dummy_frame, aes(x =dummylabels , y = dummynumbers)) + geom_bar(fill = "blue") 
p + coord_flip() + labs(title = "Title")
```

I get the following error message, which I cannot make sense of

```
Error : Mapping a variable to y and also using stat="bin".
  With stat="bin", it will attempt to set the y value to the count of cases in each group.
  This can result in unexpected behavior and will not be allowed in a future version of ggplot2.
  If you want y to represent counts of cases, use stat="bin" and don't map a variable to y.
  If you want y to represent values in the data, use stat="identity".
  See ?geom_bar for examples. (Defunct; last used in version 0.9.2)
```

Why do I get this error?

Comment: Welcome to SO! The error says for itself, really :) You map to variable `y` => you want "raw" y-values from data, but `stat = "bin"` produces counts instead of "raw" data, so there's a conceptual conflict.

Answer (score 3):

From the error message you got:

> If you want y to represent values in the data, use stat="identity".

geom_bar expects to be used as a histogram, where it bins the data itself and calculates heights based on frequency. This is the `stat="bin"` behaviour, and is the default. It throws an error, as you gave it a y value too. To fix it, you want `stat="identity"`:

```
p <- ggplot(data = dummy_frame, aes(x = dummylabels, y = dummynumbers)) +
            geom_bar(fill = "blue", stat = "identity") +
            coord_flip() + 
            labs(title = "Title")
p
```